# Example of a non-Cauchy sequence

Tags: analysis

Give an example of a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $\Bbb R$ such that for every $k\in\Bbb N$ we have $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}(x_{n+k}-x_n) = 0$ but $\{x_n\}$ is not a Cauchy sequence.

I think I should use a slowly increasing function, but don't know if I'm correct.

Comment: [The second paragraph?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence)

Answer (score 5):

The example that first comes to mind is the harmonic series

$$x_n = \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m}$$

It is well known that this series is divergent (for example, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896448/proving-that-sum-k-1-infty-frac1k-diverges)), but

$$x_{n+k} - x_n = \sum_{m=n+1}^{n+k} \frac{1}{m} < \sum_{m=n+1}^{n+k} \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{k}{n}$$

which goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

---

A simpler example is $x_n = \ln n$. The natural log is unbounded, but

$$x_{n+k} - x_n = \ln(n+k) - \ln(k) = \ln\left(\frac{n+k}{n}\right)$$

which goes to $\ln(1) = 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: +1 for $x_n=\ln(n)$. You should add some more detail, though.

Comment: @AlexS I've expanded it a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I also showed that is not Cauchy.

Answer (score 4):

The sequence may even by bounded: Try $x_n=\sin\sqrt n$.